# Translate AST to Three Address Code

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

so I have to build a simple compiler for a simple language, I used Haskell's Alex and Happy to build the parser, and it is printing the right AST's already, so next step I haveto do is to translate that data structure to another one, that represents the program in Three Address Code.

I'm yet a bit lost on how to do this, so, using Haskell data structure, how can I translate an AST to it's three Address Code? would really appreciate some help :)

thanks in advance !

Comment: What did you try so far? This is just the parser, forget about that for a moment. What would a data type representing three address code look like? Can you make a function that takes your AST to that type?

Comment: The first step is to define a data structure for your three-address code that you wish to translate into.

Comment: Hi, haven't tried much, just been reading about three address code, but all in C so i'm kinda lost... the structure has to be data (in haskell) so yes I could use a fucntion that takes the parse tree output and prints its 3 address code, any sugestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parser is quite irrelevant to this question - which seems to be, how do I translate one AST to another. To address this I will use a simplified language. Also, the code below is not intended to be simple, but easily extensible and maintainable.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.State 
import Control.Monad.Reader 

import Control.Monad.Free 
import Data.Functor.Foldable 
import qualified Data.Set as S

data Ident = Ident Int deriving (Eq)

data ExpF a = IntLitF Int
           | PlusF a a
           | IntVarF Ident  deriving (Eq, Functor)

data Exp = IntLit Int
           | Plus Exp Exp
           | IntVar Ident  deriving (Eq)

data Cmd
  = CmdAtrib Ident Exp 
  | CmdSeq Cmd Cmd 
  | CmdNone deriving (Eq)

data TAC_F r = Assign Ident (ExpF Ident) r deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

type TAC = Free TAC_F ()

(=:) :: Ident -> ExpF Ident -> TAC 
(=:) i e = Free (Assign i e (Pure ()))
```

Some of the above definitions might seem strange. `ExpF` and `Exp` are defined in the recursion schemes style and used the `recursion-schemes` package. [More info.](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/recursion-schemes/catamorphisms) `TAC` is defined in terms of `Free` because like the name implies, you get monad syntax for free. The only thing that `a >> b` does for `TAC` is creates the ast which contains `a` followed by `b`.

You need a way to generate fresh variables:

```
freshVar :: Monad m => StateT [Ident] m Ident 
freshVar = do
  s <- get
  case s of 
    [] -> put [Ident (-1)] >> return (Ident (-1))
    (Ident x:xs) -> put (Ident (x-1) : xs) >> return (Ident (x-1))
```

I use a list because it is simple but you may want to attach more information to your identifiers, in which case you should use `Data.Set.Set` or `Data.Map.Map`. By convention, fresh variables are negative while quantified variables are positive. Not a very sophisticted method, but it works.

Now this is where the magic happens. Thanks to recursion schemes, recursion over the tree is very simple:

```
translateExp :: Exp -> State [Ident] (TAC, Ident)
translateExp = cata go where 
  go (PlusF a b) = do 
    (ae,av) <- a
    (be,bv) <- b
    t <- freshVar
    return (ae >> be >> t =: PlusF av bv, t)
  go (IntLitF i) = do 
    t <- freshVar 
    return (t =: IntLitF i, t)
  go (IntVarF a) = return (return (), a)

translateCmd :: Cmd -> State [Ident] TAC
translateCmd (CmdAtrib ident exp) = do
  (e,v) <- translateExp exp 
  return (e >> ident =: IntVarF v)
translateCmd (CmdSeq a b) = do
  x <- translateCmd a 
  y <- translateCmd b 
  return (x >> y)
translateCmd CmdNone = return (return ())
```

Then an example:

```
test0 = CmdSeq (CmdAtrib (Ident 1) (IntLit 10 `Plus` IntVar (Ident 2)))
               (CmdAtrib (Ident 3) (IntVar (Ident 1) `Plus` IntVar (Ident 1) `Plus` IntVar (Ident 2)))

>putStrLn $ showTAC $ fst $ runState (translateCmd test0) []
t1 =: 10
t2 =: t1 + v2
v1 =: t2
t3 =: v1 + v1
t4 =: t3 + v2
v3 =: t4
```

Note that variables bound by the LHS of `CmdAtrib` will never collide with those found in the RHS.

---

Boilerplate / show instances:

```
instance Show Ident where 
  show (Ident i) | i < 0 = "t" ++ show (abs i)
                 | otherwise = "v" ++ show i

instance Show a => Show (ExpF a) where 
  show (IntLitF i) = show i
  show (PlusF a b) = show a ++ " + " ++ show b 
  show (IntVarF i) = show i 

type instance Base Exp = ExpF  
instance Foldable Exp where 
  project (IntLit i) = IntLitF i
  project (Plus a b) = PlusF a b
  project (IntVar b) = IntVarF b

instance Show Cmd where 
  show (CmdAtrib i e) = show i ++ " <- " ++ show e 
  show (CmdSeq a b) = show a ++ " ;\n " ++ show b  
  show (CmdNone) = ""

instance Show Exp where 
  show (IntLit i) = show i
  show (Plus a b) = show a ++ " + " ++ show b 
  show (IntVar i) = show i 

showTAC (Free (Assign i exp xs)) = show i ++ " =: " ++ show exp ++ "\n" ++ showTAC xs 
showTAC (Pure a) = ""
```

Comment: thks for answering, as I try to compile your example I get "Illegal family instance for 'Base'. Anything missing ?

Comment: The error you get should suggest that you enable `TypeFamilies`.

Comment: So I removed Exp and ExpF from your sample and tried to adapt my Exp data structure to the code, got a compiling error "Exp is applied to too many type arguments" in the data type declaration for TAC_F, why didnt that happen with ExpF and happens with mine ?

Comment: You can't remove `ExpF`, you should expand it as well. If you don't have `ExpF` you can't have `ExpF Ident`. The structure of `ExpF Ident` and `Exp` are completely different. `ExpF Ident` contains no substructure, only an `Indent` in the places that `Exp` contains more `Exp`s. You will have to have 2 datatypes no matter what.

Comment: I forgot the show instance for Ident. It is pretty straightforward but I added it anyways.

Comment: Given some `data Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }`, `Exp` can be replaced by `Fix ExpF`. See the first section of  http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html for a nice explanation of the fixed point of a functor.